# After Load Template callback AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-template

I want to execute a carousel plugin but i can't find the right callback("After load all template content") for this.
Basically i have a template which has a lot of loop throw json objects.

```
 Blog.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {    
        return $routeProvider.otherwise({
          templateUrl: '../assets/angularlayouttoload.html',
          controller: 'blogControllers'
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```

This is my controller getting json data.

```
blogControllers.controller('blogControllers', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
  $scope.data = {carrossel: [], banner: []};

  $http.get('public/index.json').success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.data.carrossel = data[0];
    $scope.data.banner = data[1];  

    // After Load all template execute this above 
    $('.bxslider_new_one').bxSlider({auto: true, speed: 1000, pause: 10000, pagerCustom: $("div#pager_for_slider_new_one")});

  }).error(function() {
    console.error('Failed to load posts.');
  });              
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be making DOM calls like this with Angular: It's simply not the way Angular is suppose to work. Instead you would want to make a directive:

```
.directive('bxSlider', [function() {
  return {
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $element.bxSlider({
        auto: true, 
        speed: 1000, 
        pause: 10000, p
        pagerCustom: $element.find('.pager');
    }
  };
}]);
```

Then you can use it within your template:

```
  <div bx:slider>
    <a class="pager">foo</a>
  </div>
```

Here is one of the better introductions to custom directives: http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html#.Ut51i_Yo5AY